# Iterate over a tuple in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting

I know I can iterate over a list in bash like so:

```sh
for reg in xmm ymm zmm; do
  echo "Reg is $reg"
done
```

Great.

What if I want to iterate over a list of *tuples*, like (fake syntax):

```sh
for reg, size in (xmm, 128) (ymm, 256) (zmm, 512); do
  echo "Reg $reg has size $size"
done
```

It should print out:

```
Reg xmm has size 128
Reg ymm has size 256
Reg ymm has size 512
```

What is a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate over strings that you can split using `read`. For example:

```
while IFS=, read -r reg size; do
    echo "Reg $reg has size $size"
done <<EOF
xmm,128
ymm,256
zmm,521
EOF
```

or

```
for x in xmm,128 ymm,256 zmm,512; do
    IFS=, read reg size <<< "$x"
    echo "Reg $reg has size $size"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` in process substitution and read it in 2 variable in a while loop like this:

```
while read -r reg size; do
    echo "Reg $reg has size $size"
done < <(printf '%s %s\n' xmm 128 ymm 256 zmm 512)
```

```
Reg xmm has size 128
Reg ymm has size 256
Reg zmm has size 512
```

You may also use this alternate `printf` command:

```
printf '%s\n' 'xmm 128' 'ymm 256' 'zmm 512'
```